# Мониторинг трафика

Tags: поиск-программ, трафик, мониторинг

В организации около 20 компов (W7), к сожалению нет возможности пустить все компы через сервер,  по этой причине доступ к интернету у всех компьютеров через wi-fi роутер.

Какую программу можно поставить, чтобы снимать показания интернет трафика в сети с других компов? Если еще и список посещаемых сайтов можно будет вытаскивать, то это будет просто замечательно.

Comment: Вам сниффер-то куда поставить нужно? На каждый компьютер или как?

Comment: Да на все комы что-то типа синифера  а все данные тянуть на свой комп!

Comment: А что за вай-вай роутер, он статистику умеет собирать?

Comment: ASUS с ТОМАТОМ, Там учет есть, но мне важно знать  трафик по IPшникам а он показывает общий либо по интерфейсам, так же желательно детальный лог видеть кто куда "ходил" !

Comment:  1. Что за роутер? (модель)
 2. Почему нет возможности пустить всех через сервер? (может всё не так сложно)

Comment: ASUS WL-500Gp Premium V2, TOMATO v.1.28, Через сервак пробовал но что не никак не могу настроить его правильно! Сам я "любитель" в компах по этому делаю пока то что могу!

Answer (score 2):

Мой любименький простенький `AutoIT`!

Заюзаем библиотеку [`winpcap`](http://opensource.grisambre.net/pcapau3/) и сам [`драйвер`](http://www.winpcap.org/).

И собстно готовый код:

```
#include <Array.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
#Include <GuiListView.au3>
#include <StaticConstants.au3>
#include <EditConstants.au3>
#Include <WinAPI.au3>
#include <ComboConstants.au3>

#include <Winpcap.au3>

$winpcap=_PcapSetup()
If ($winpcap=-1) Then
    MsgBox(16,"Pcap error !","WinPcap not found !")
    exit
EndIf

$pcap_devices=_PcapGetDeviceList()
If ($pcap_devices=-1) Then
    MsgBox(16,"Pcap error !",_PcapGetLastError())
    exit
EndIf

$int=SelectInterface($pcap_devices)

$pcap=_PcapStartCapture($pcap_devices[$int][0],"host "&$pcap_devices[$int][7]&" and tcp port (80 or 8080)",0,65536,2^24,0)
If IsInt($pcap) Then
    MsgBox(16,"Pcap error !",_PcapGetLastError())
    _PcapFree()
    exit
 EndIf

$file = FileOpen("domains.txt", 1)

; Check if file opened for writing OK
If $file = -1 Then
    MsgBox(0, "Error", "Unable to open file.")
    Exit
 EndIf

$i=0
Do

    If IsPtr($pcap) Then    ; If $pcap is a Ptr, then the capture is running
        $time0=TimerInit()
        While (TimerDiff($time0)<500) ; Retrieve packets from queue for maximum 500ms before returning to main loop, not to "hang" the window for user
            $packet=_PcapGetPacket($pcap)
            If IsInt($packet) Then ExitLoop

            $http=HttpCapture($packet[3])

            If $http == False Then ContinueLoop

            FileWriteLine($file, $http & @CRLF)
            $i+=1
        Wend
    EndIf

Until false

; close all remaining open captures
For $j=0 to Ubound($recordings)-2
    _WinAPI_CloseHandle($recordings[$j][1])
Next

; close winpcap wrapper
_PcapStopCapture($pcap)
_PcapFree()

Func HttpCapture ($data)    
    Local $ipheaderlen=BitAnd(_PcapBinaryGetVal($data,15,1),0xF)*4
    Local $tcpoffset=$ipheaderlen+14
    Local $tcplen=_PcapBinaryGetVal($data,17,2)-$ipheaderlen  ; ip total len - ip header len
    Local $tcpheaderlen=BitShift(_PcapBinaryGetVal($data, $tcpoffset+13,1),4)*4
    Local $tcpsrcport=_PcapBinaryGetVal($data,$tcpoffset+1,2) 
    Local $tcpdstport=_PcapBinaryGetVal($data,$tcpoffset+3,2) 
    Local $tcpsequence=_PcapBinaryGetVal($data,$tcpoffset+5,4) 
    Local $tcpflags=_PcapBinaryGetVal($data, $tcpoffset+14,1)
    Local $r[2]=["",""]

    ; From here, we are watching http payload
    Local $httpoffset=$tcpoffset+$tcpheaderlen+1
    Local $httplen=$tcplen-$tcpheaderlen
    If $httplen=0 Then return false

    Local $http=BinaryToString(BinaryMid ($data, $httpoffset, $httplen))

    Local $host = StringRegExp ( $http, "Host: (.*)" , 1)

    If @Error<>0 Then return false

    return $host[0]
EndFunc

Func SelectInterface($devices) ; auto selects an ethernet pcap interface or prompt user for choice
    Local $ipv4=0,$int=0,$i,$win0,$first,$interface,$ok,$which,$msg
    For $i=0 To Ubound($devices)-1
        If $devices[$i][3]="EN10MB" AND StringLen($devices[$i][7])>6 Then ; for ethernet devices with valid ip address only !
            $ipv4+=1
            $int=$i
        EndIf
    Next
    If $ipv4=0 Then
        MsgBox(16,"Error","No network interface found with a valid IPv4 address !")
        _PcapFree()
        Exit
    EndIf
    If $ipv4>1 Then
        $win0=GUICreate("Interface choice", 500, 50)
        $interface=GUICtrlCreateCombo("", 10, 15, 400,default,$CBS_DROPDOWNLIST)
        $first=true
        For $i = 0 to Ubound($devices)-1
            If $devices[$i][3]="EN10MB" AND StringLen($devices[$i][7])>6 Then 
                If $first Then 
                    GUICtrlSetData(-1, $devices[$i][7]&" - "&_PcapCleanDeviceName($devices[$i][1]),$devices[$i][7]&" - "&_PcapCleanDeviceName($devices[$i][1]))
                    $first=false
                Else
                    GUICtrlSetData(-1, $devices[$i][7]&" - "&_PcapCleanDeviceName($devices[$i][1]))
                EndIf
            EndIf
        Next
        $ok=GUICtrlCreateButton ( " Ok ", 430, 15,60) 
        GUISetState()
        While true
            $msg = GUIGetMsg()
            If $msg=$ok Then
                $which=GUICtrlRead($interface)
                For $i=0 To Ubound($devices)-1
                    If StringLen($devices[$i][7])>6 AND StringInStr($which,$devices[$i][7]) Then 
                        $int=$i
                        ExitLoop
                    EndIf
                Next
                GUIDelete($win0)
                ExitLoop
            EndIf
            If $msg=$GUI_EVENT_CLOSE Then Exit
        Wend
    EndIF
    return $int
EndFunc
```

Можно вынимать что угодно, начиная то адреса и заканчивая контентом.

Если хотим большего, то делаем заказ :-) Или сами вояем - тоже доставляет.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, буду разбираться что к чему и с чем это есть!